# In Apache Spark Java how can I remove elements from a dataset where some field does not match

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset say:

```
a=1, b=2
a=2, b=2
a=2, b=3
```

...and I want to drop records where `a` has the same value but `b` has a different value. In this case dropping both records where `a=2`.

I suspect I need to `groupBy` for `a` then some kind of filtering where `b != b`.

Comment: Should duplicate rows be dropped as well?

Comment: @Kafels good question. Yes they should but I can do that before executing this op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did my solution using scala, just follow the idea:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{Window}

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, 2),
  (2, 2),
  (2, 3)
)).toDF("a", "b")

val window = Window.partitionBy("a")
val newDF = (df
             .withColumn("count", count(lit(1)).over(window))
             .where(col("count") === lit(1))
             .drop("count"))

newDF.show
```

Output:

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
+---+---+
```